# First row Id value apply as all rows Id in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json

There is a draggable `tr` in a table. My purpose is after dragging and confirm it clicking a button order list is updating in the database. To do that I have created a JSON object. I want to save there id s and updated new orders to JSON object.

But my JSON object only first `id` is saved for all. It means the first-row id is applied for all rows. All `updated_order` is saved well. How can I save all `id` save to DB. Should I use a loop. How can I solve this

I have mentioned tried code.

```
 jQuery("table tbody tr").each(function (index, value) {
    id = $('.orderid').data("value"); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code will always return the first item it finds because you're not limiting the search to just one row but all the td's with `.orderid` as it's class.

```
id = $('.orderid').data("value");
```

You need to find the element from the loop element it's parsing.
In your `$.each()` function `.each(function (index, value)` you have an `index` (0, 1, 2, etc) and a `value` which is your `tr` element. You will need to use your `value` to find the `.orderid` element. Something like this:

```
id = $(value).find('.orderid').data("value");
```